# Возможность создания составного первичного ключа MySQL

Tags: mysql

Всем привет.

Интересует вопрос может ли первичный суррогатный ключ некой таблицы входить в какой- нибудь составной первичный ключ этой же таблицы?

Comment: Не может, по той причине, что в таблице не может быть двух первичных ключей. Дополнительные уникальные ключи могут быть, но они не первичные

Comment: @Mike, благодарю